# Dynamically loading Python "editable" modules: What is the correct way of doing it?

Tags: python, python-importlib

Python's documentation includes [a great way to enumerate installed packages](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/creating-and-discovering-plugins/) that satisfy some basic requirements.

This works flawlesly if the package is "fully" installed.

When the package has been installed as "editable" (via `pip install -e ...`) then using the above way of listing packages results in descriptions such as:

```
__editable___some_package_name_0_0_1_finder
```

If we now try to import this module, we still get back a "module" object but one that has not been "executed" yet.

So, if you tried to:

```
import importlib

t = importlib.import_module("__editable___some_package_name_0_0_1_finder")
```

Then `t` is of type `module` but its contents are not the contents of the module.

I think that this is because when a package is installed as editable, then `pip` takes advantage of an [import hook](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html) that affects the way the module is loaded.

Finally, one of the attributes of the `t` variable from above is `MAPPING` which is a dictionary from the canonical package name to the path it is actually installed. If we were to do:

```
z = importlib.import_module(list(t.MAPPING.keys())[0])
```

Then `z` contains exactly what we expect it to (all the members of the module).

So, the question is this:

1. Is it better to have two separate scan processes, one for modules that are installed normally and one for "editable" modules? (The only difference between them being the extra step of accessing the `MAPPING` to properly load the module).
2. Would it still be reliable if I extracted the package name from its `name` attribute with a regex?
3. Is there something I am missing with these "...finder.py" modules? Is it possible to still instantiate the module properly with the information returned by `importlib` 's `import_module`?